# Display time in irssi in 12-hour format

Tags: irc, irssi

In the [irssi](http://www.irssi.org/) IRC client, the time and timestamps are displayed by default in 24-hour format. Is there any way to get it to default to 12-hour format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, I just did `/set timestamp_format %I:%M`.

Comment: Technically that is is wrong. You need an uppercase M, or else you will get thew hour and month.c Like at 10:45 in february, you would see 10:02. It needs to be %I%M.